# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error que me impide abrir mi proyecto?

Tags: delphi-tokyo

Necesito ayuda urgente para solucionar este problema, ya que no puedo abrir el proyecto que estuve creando en Delphi.

Me sale este error que no consigo solucionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a tu pregunta las primeras líneas del fichero DPROJ de tu proyecto? Se está quejando de ese fichero, así que es importante para saber qué está pasando. cuanta más información tenga la pregunta será más fácil encontrar la solución.